# Can I reuse paths between OpenApi service specifications?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm documenting a set of services with open-api 3.0.3. Each shares a set of common endpoint paths. Is there a way to define a `path` and reuse in multiple specifications? This would be functionally equivalent to the other [components](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) sections.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible.

Comment: This link shows a #ref for path item object:
https://swagger.io/specification/#path-item-object